# using bz2.decompress in python,but the answers different

Tags: python, bzip2, compression

I have a string like this:

```
un: 'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
pw: 'BZh91AY&SY\x94$|\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x81\x00\x03$ \x00!\x9ah3M\x13<]\xc9\x14\xe1BBP\x91\xf08'
```

and this is my code:

```
un = re.search(r"un: '(.+)'",page).group(1)
bz2.decompress(un)
```

then I use the `bz2.decompress` method, it returns error:

```
IOError: invalid data stream
```

and I try this:

```
un = 'BZh91...\x084'
bz2.decompress(un)
```

and it returns the correct answer.

**Supplement**：this is my complete code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib
import re 
import bz2

def main():
    page=urllib.urlopen("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/integrity.html").read()
    unstring = re.search(r"un: *'(.+)'",page).group(1)
    print unstring
    un = "BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084"
    #the string un is copied from output of 'print unstring'
    print bz2.decompress (un)
    print bz2.decompress (unstring)
if (__name__=="__main__"):
    main()
```

this is the output:

```
==== No Subprocess ====
>>> 
BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084
huge
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/terry/pythonchallage/pythonchallenge_8.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/terry/pythonchallage/pythonchallenge_8.py", line 14, in main
    print bz2.decompress (unstring)
IOError: invalid data stream
>>>
```

Comment: What does `prin(repr(un))` show? Are those `\xhh` escapes actual bytes or 4 charecters long each?

Comment: I would guess that your RE is taking both the `un` and the `pw` values, with the `pw:` in the middle. Just try to print it before decompressing.

Comment: BTW, I've just tried, and the `pw` decompresses right, but the `un` is wrong. Maybe you have a typo...

Comment: The sample post you gave us **is** invalid.

Comment: Off topic, but did you notice that you just published you password on the Internet? (`pw` stands for _password_, doesn't it?)

Comment: @rodrigo: it doesn't matter, since the stream is corrupted anyway.

Comment: Is it me, or does it seem unusual to be compressing username and password fields... how can a practical length for these fields be worthy of compression?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thks for your help,i think my string is right,the string un is copied from the answer (the output of 'print unstring' after regax).i update my question and push the complete code and output

Comment: @terry_love_c: right, you have a string literal there. Use `print repr(unstring)` and you'll see the `\xhh` are printed as `\\xhh` instead, meaning the backslash is a literal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i tried    'print(repr(unstring))'    .the output is    'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'

Comment: @terry_love_c: I already reproduced the issue; you are getting `'BZh91AY&SYA\\xaf\\x82\\r\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x80\\x02\\xc0\\x02\\x00 \\x00!\\x9ah3M\\x07<]\\xc9\\x14\\xe1BA\\x06\\xbe\\x084'` in that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Awkwardly！！I am sorry，it just the same like you say，i enter print(repr(un)),so stupid i am!Thks so much!

Comment: @terry_love_c: I undeleted my original answer below a little while ago. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *string literals* there, where each `\xhh` value is 4 literal characters, not a byte escape.

If so, you'll first need to tell Python to interpret those:

```
bz2.decompress(un.decode('string_escape'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> unstring = r'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
>>> print unstring
BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084
>>> unstring
'BZh91AY&SYA\\xaf\\x82\\r\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x80\\x02\\xc0\\x02\\x00 \\x00!\\x9ah3M\\x07<]\\xc9\\x14\\xe1BA\\x06\\xbe\\x084'
>>> import bz2
>>> bz2.decompress(unstring)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: invalid data stream
>>> bz2.decompress(unstring.decode('string_escape'))
'huge'
```

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn points out, the data is actually invalid, so it won't decompress.

Further to this, assuming no typo in your question, is another potential problem: your regex pattern expects there to be a space after `un:`, but there is no such space in your sample string. You could change the regex to be `r"un: *'(.+)'"` which would permit zero or more spaces between the `:` and the `'`.

Comment: The data stream is simply invalid though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : so it is. Updated answer.